# PHP MySql Table creation - So simple but not working. WHY?

Tags: php, mysql

I am confronted to a problem that is driving me crazy. I really do not get it. Here below a very simple table creation. I would like to use a variable to name the table. And it is not working!!!!! If I replace the variable by a "handwriten" name, it works... What the.... Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc. In case I did not mentionne it, it is driving me crazy.

```
$processid = mysql_thread_id();

mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE '.$processid.'
(
bat_file varchar(255), 
bat_file_date datetime, 
bat_file_misc varchar(255), 
bat_titre varchar(255), 
bat_lien varchar(255)
)';

mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Comment: I did not put all the code. As I said, if I replace the variable by a handwriten name it works....

Comment: You are not doing any error checking after your query, so the query would fail silently if there are any problems. The manual on `mysql_query()` shows how to check for errors. And if it doesn't work with `$processid`, but works with a manually entered name, wouldn't the first thing to do be looking at what value it has?

Comment: I echoed out $processid, and wrote the value manually as name, and it works...

Comment: Ah, okay. Can you show an example of `$processid`? Maybe the problem is that the table already exists?

Comment: no the table does not exist...

Comment: Litte explanation for the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of [`mysql_thread_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-thread-id.php) is not a [valid name for a table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) unless you quote it:

> Certain objects within MySQL, including database, table, index,
>   column, alias, view, stored procedure, partition, and other object
>   names are known as identifiers.

```
 ...
```

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist
>   solely of digits.

Since the quote character is the backtick, it should work if you change it to

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE `'.$processid.'` ... ';
```

I don't know why you want to create a table named after a `mysql_thread_id` (it sounds *really* fishy), but even if there is a perfectly good reason it might be a good idea to add a prefix in front so that you don't *have* to quote it each time.

Comment: Hello Jon. Thanks for trying to help. The weird thing is that when I create a table manually only consisting of digits, the table is created properly...

Comment: @Marc: I don't know why that would work, as on the surface it should always be disallowed. Did you try quoting to see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: Working like a charm :) Thank you very much Jon, you rock !!